# How to filter my list of tuples of two input lists?

Tags: list, haskell, filter

I am trying to generate all possibles combinations from two lists and then only return those that match the lambda function. So I currently have the following code:

```
func :: [a] -> [b] -> ((a, b) -> Bool) -> [(a, b)]
func xs ys f = filter f (tup)
    where
        tup = concat(map (\x -> map (\y -> (x,y))ys) xs)
```

Currently I am able to generate all the possible combinations, but the filtering won't work.

Error for the input : `func [1,2,3] [4,5] (\ a b -> a+b > 6)`

`• Couldn't match expected type ‘Bool’ with actual type ‘(a, b) -> Bool’`

`• The lambda expression ‘\ a b -> a + b > 7’ has two value arguments, but its type ‘(a, b) -> Bool’ has only one`

How can I solve this?

I tried to use `map` instead of `filter`, but that did not work as well.

Comment: You almost got it, try `func [1, 2, 3] [4, 5] (\(a, b) -> a+b > 6)` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Making a function with two arguments and making a function with a single 2-tuple argument use slightly different syntax:

```
\a b -> a+b > 6 -- two arguments
\(a, b) -> a+b > 6 -- one tuple argument
```